# Unison over SSH, connection with server lost although SSH works

Tags: ssh, unison

I have just rebuilt my file server after it suffered disk corruption. When I tried to re-sync data using Unison, I got the error message

> Lost connection with the server

I retried from the command line and got:

```
~$ unison someprofile -ui text
Contacting server...
Unison failed: Fatal error: Error in creating unison directory /home/user/.unison:
File exists [mkdir(/home/user/.unison)]
Fatal error: Lost connection with the server
```

I can open an SSH connection to the server. Both client and server run the same Unison version. What’s up here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lost connection with the server** does not necessarily mean a network issue – it can also mean that the remote Unison instance terminated the connection for whatever reason. (Because Unison is designed to work with different SSH backends, there is no reliable way to get any more detail about why the connection ended.)

Since at least Unison 2.52, the GUI should display any error messages from the server.

For those on an older version, running unison in text mode, i.e.

```
unison <profile> -ui text
```

where `<profile>` equals any profile (`*.prf` file in your local `.unison` dir, minus the `.prf` extension), will give you a detailed error message.

Here, the lines after `Contacting server` and before `Fatal error: Lost connection with the server` are the errors we got from the remote system: it tried to create a dir at `~/.unison` (because there was no dir at that path) but failed because there was another filesystem object at that path.

In this case, `~/.unison` on the server was a broken symlink, as I had placed the `.unison` dir on a different filesystem than the home dir. The solution was to fix that symlink (i.e. recreate the dir at the path the symlink points to).